# Where to place a method for listing objects

Tags: java, model-view-controller, oop

I'm making my first Java project, and trying to learn OO programming as well as MVC.

Say that you have a class "Products" and a number of objects of that class. Your GUI want to display a list of these objects, possibly also with some filter etc. I can think of several ways to do this:

- The GUI could simply read all objects and list them.
- Make a globally available method that returns all the objects. This could be placed in some kind of repository for global functions.
- Make a static method inside the Products class that returns a list of all objects.

What is the proper way to do this, and where would you put the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to learn MVC, you already know that in order to implement MVC pattern you need three layers: Model, View, Controller. In your case, you have the two of the layers, Model (*Product*) and View (*ProductGUI*, assuming this is a different class). What you are missing is the Controller.

In order to leverage from MVC, I suggest you to implement the Controller layer with an API approach so that you have an interface, `ProductController`; and a class implementing the interface, `ProductControllerImpl`. This interface-class separation lets you to switch between alternative implementations and also allows Mocking your services for user interface testing (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for further explanations).

Let me also try to explain this with a simple example.

Assume you create the interface for your Controller layer as such:

```
public interface ProductController {
    public List<Product> listProducts();
    public List<Product> listProducts(NameFilter nameFilter);
}
```

Then you can create a Mock implementation for this interface for testing purposes as such:

```
public class ProductControllerImplMock implements ProductController {
    List<Product> products;

    public ProductControllerImplMock() {
        products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    public List<Product> listProducts() {
        products.add(new Product("A"));
        products.add(new Product("B"));
        return products;
    }

    public List<Product> listProducts(NameFilter nameFilter) {
        products.add(new Product("A"));
        return products;
    }
}
```

Note: Assumining you have a NameFilter class that aims at filtering Product's by name.

If you decide to use a database to store your products, then you can implement `ProductControllerDatabaseImpl` which will query your database and retrieve entities for listing and which will most probably introduce `WHERE` clause to the query for `listProducts(NameFilter)` method.

Actually, things are never this simple. What is shown in this example will be referred to as DAO (Data Access Object) in more complex applications and there will be a separate layer, generally called Business layer instead of Controller layer, which will implement the actual logic for the application. But I tried to keep the example as simple as possible for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the OOP approach would be to expose the collection via a basic accessor method in the `Products` class. If you're concerned about the collection being modified, either wrap the collection with one of the unmodifiable collections made available by the [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class, or return a copy.

**Edit -** 
And concerning the GUI, be aware of concurrency-related issues.

**Example -**

```
final class Products
{
    private final List<Foo> listOfFoo;

    Products(List<Foo> listOfFoo)
    {
        this.listOfFoo = listOfFoo;
    }

    public List<Foo> getListOfFoo()
    {
        if(listOfFoo.isEmpty())
        {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(listOfFoo);
    }
}
```